# Is there a solution to get the stock ICS Dialer and People apps with Touchwiz devices?

Tags: phone-app, samsung-galaxy-note, people-app

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Note with the stock Touchwiz UI ROM. I was wondering if there's a standalone ICS Dialer and People app available? I've managed to find a standalone messaging and calendar app which works just fine but have been unable to find the People app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently not. I checked with some people on XDA. I just rooted and upgraded to CM10.